# Kafka what will happen with message if a consumer group member goes down?

Tags: apache-kafka

Suppose we have a topic named `Topic` and a consumer group `CG` with three consumers. The group offset equals to 0.

The consumers start to read messages.

Read sequence:

1. Consumer 1 reads message 1.
2. Consumer 2 reads message 2.
3. Consumer 3 reads message 3.
4. Consumer 2 commits message 2.
5. Consumer 3 commits message 3.
6. Consumer 1 fails on processing of message 1 and goes down.

The question is: what will happen with message 1?

Or maybe I understand wrongly how consumers do read the messages as I am new to Kafka.

Version: Apache Kafka 2.4.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed about [partitions](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#intro_consumers), **Multiple consumers of same group will never consume messages from same partition**

Suppose if you have the topic with three partitions(P0,P1,P2),and if you have three consumers(C1,C2,C3) of same group then each one will start consuming from each partition

[image]

If any consumer fails to submit offset and go down, then it will again start consuming the messages from previous offset (in your case 0)

Suppose if you have topic of 5 partition (P0,P1,P2,P3,P4) and of three consumers (C0,C1,C3) of same group. Then consumers will try to load balance equally by each taking two partition 
[image]

C1 consumes from P0 and P1, and C2 consumes from P2 and P3 and remaining C3 consumes from P4.

Comment: So if C3 consumes all messaged from its own partition will kafka (or kafka client) re-assign other partitions to itself to help other consumers?

Comment: No kafka will not resign anything like that @PrisacariDmitrii

Answer (score 2):

Each consumer will have partitions assigned to them. 
Let's say we have 6 partitions:

Consumer 1: Partiton 1 & 2
Consumer 2: Partition 3 & 4
Consumer 3: Partition 5 & 6

When Consumer 1 goes down, the consumer group will re-balance and assign the free partitions to the other consumers, thus giving us the following setup:

Consumer 2: Partition **1** & 3 & 4
Consumer 3: Partition **2** & 5 & 6

The other consumers will start off from the last committed offset on that partition.